# Failed to compile my SASS Variables

Tags: css, sass, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

Here is my Sass Code

```
@charset "UTF-8";
$primary-color : #000000;
.cl_primary {
    background: $primary-color !important;
    color:white !important;
    border-color:$primary-color !important;
}
.cl_primary:hover {
    background: #ffffff !important;
    color:$primary-color !important;
}
```

And That is how I imported in my theme.liquid

```
{{ 'style.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

and here what I got the error when I inspect

```
.cl_primary {
    background: $primary-color !important;
    color: white !important;
    border-color: $primary-color !important;
}
```

With Yellow Warning "Invalid Property Value". Can anybody see why Shopify is not running the code through the SASS compilation phase?

Comment: I don't know why Shopify don't compile my Sass

Comment: This works for me just as is. Your stylesheet file should be named style.scss.liquid though. The import you have is fine. Just make sure the actual stylesheet is named as such.